# How to press enter key automatically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I press enter key without hitting the enter key using Jquery. 
I have a dropdown list. after selecting the any value from dropdown, the value of list will copy in input box(search box). After then I want to call Enter key event automatically using jquery.
Please refer following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    var data = [
                            {
                                "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
                                "position":   "System Architect",
                                "salary":     "$3,120",
                                "start_date": "2011/04/25",
                                "office":     "Edinburgh",
                                "extn":       "5421"
                            },
                            {
                                "name":       "Black Winters",
                                "position":   "Project Engineer",
                                "salary":     "$1,300",
                                "start_date": "2018/27/05",
                                "office":     "Edinburgh",
                                "extn":       "8412"
                            },
                            {
                                "name":       "Black Winters",
                                "position":   "Project Engineer",
                                "salary":     "$1,300",
                                "start_date": "2018/27/05",
                                "office":     "Edinburgh",
                                "extn":       "8412"
                            },
                            {
                                "name":       "Orange John",
                                "position":   "Network Admin",
                                "salary":     "$3,000",
                                "start_date": "2010/10/12",
                                "office":     "Edinburgh",
                                "extn":       "8425"
                            },
                            {
                                "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
                                "position":   "System Architect",
                                "salary":     "$3,120",
                                "start_date": "2011/04/25",
                                "office":     "Edinburgh",
                                "extn":       "5421"
                            }
                                ];
                    $("#table1").DataTable({
                        data: data,
                                columns: [
                                    { data: 'name' },
                                    { data: 'position' },
                                    { data: 'salary' },
                                    { data: 'start_date' },
                                    { data: 'office' },
                                    { data: 'extn' }
                                ]
                    });

                    /* color of data table */
                    var seen = {};
                    $('#table1 tr').each(function() {
                    var txt = $(this).text();
                    if (seen[txt])
                        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                    else
                        seen[txt] = true;
                    });
                    var positionSet = new Set();
                    positionSet.add("System Architect");
                    positionSet.add("Project Engineer");
                    positionSet.add("Network Admin");

                    for(let myPositionSet of positionSet){
                        console.log(myPositionSet);
                        $('#empPosition').append($('<option>', { 
                            value: myPositionSet,
                            text : myPositionSet 
                        }));
                    }
                    $("#empPosition").change(function() {
                        $("#table1_filter input").val(this.value);
                        e = jQuery.Event("change")
                        e.which = 13 //choose the one you want
                            $("#table1_filter input").change(function(){
                             alert('keypress triggered')
                            }).trigger(e)
                    })

                });
```

Here is the HTML of this above code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <select id="empPosition">
                </select>
            <table id="table1" class="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>position</th>
                            <th>salary</th>
                            <th>start_date</th>
                            <th>office</th>
                            <th>extn</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

The code is not working as i want. After copying the value in search box It should hit the enter and then it will show the result that i have copy in search box.

Comment: There is no possible way to press enter key instead use `Trigger` function

Comment: I don't quite understand the goal here. `change` is fired after an input has lost the focus (if the value was changed). Also, the default action of hitting Enter on an input element is to submit the form containing that input ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `keyup` event instead of `change` event

```
$("#table1_filter input").val(this.value).trigger('keyup')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keypress or keydown event:

```
var keyEvent = $.Event("keydown");
keyEvent.which = 13; 
$("#table1_filter input").trigger(keyEvent);
```

Link to know keyEvent value:https://keycode.info/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider search API in Datatable instead of `enter` event

```
var dataTable = $("#table1").DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
          { data: 'name' },
          { data: 'position' },
          { data: 'salary' },
          { data: 'start_date' },
          { data: 'office' },
          { data: 'extn' }
        ]
      });

$("#empPosition").change(function (event) {
        $("#table1_filter input").val(this.value);
        dataTable.search( this.value ).draw();
})
```

https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()